# Loading sub items of TreeView in background

Tags: c#, multithreading, wpf, mvvm

I am working with a `TreeView` (default control from .Net Framework) that displays hierachical data. Data are bound to the view using MVVM pattern with the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The child items are loaded automatically when the view requests the child collection. To stay responsive, the child items are loaded in background up to a specific depth:

```
public class TreeItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> myChildren = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>();
    private const int PRELOADING_DEPTH = 1;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoading { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => EnsureChildrenAreLoaded(myChildren, 0));
            return myChildren;
        }
    }

    public void EnsureChildrenAreLoaded(ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> childrenToFill, int depth)
    {
        if (!IsLoaded && !IsLoading)
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            var children = LoadChildren().ToArray();
            App.RunOnGuiThread(() =>
            {
                foreach (var child in children)
                    childrenToFill.Add(child);
                IsLoaded = true;
                IsLoading = false;
            });
        }
        if (depth < PRELOADING_DEPTH)
            foreach (var child in myChildren)
                child.EnsureChildrenAreLoaded(child.myChildren, depth + 1);
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<TreeItemViewModel> LoadChildren()
    {
        // logic for loading sub items
        return Enumerable.Empty<TreeItemViewModel>();
    }
}
```

RunOnGuiThread:

```
    public static void RunOnGuiThread(Action action)
    {
        if (Current == null || Current.Dispatcher == null)
            action();
        else
            Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
```

Is that a proper solution? Has it any disadvantages / potential for improvements?

Comment: A single edit after a year and you already got two answers ;-)

Comment: Monday morning seems to be a good time for asking questions ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see your full UI then maybe you're using it (to display a *busy indicator*?) but, from what I have here, it seems that `IsLoading` is just a repetition for `IsLoaded` and as such it should be dropped. Any reason for `EnsureChildrenAreLoaded()` to be `public` and `TreeItemViewModel` not to be `sealed`?

`EnsureChildrenAreLoaded()` **might** be:

```
var children = LoadChildren().ToArray();
App.RunOnGuiThread(() =>
{
    foreach (var child in children)
        childrenToFill.Add(child);

    IsLoaded = true;
});
```

However we now have the *problem* to preload the children. My major concern here is that you're queuing an action in the pool each time you read the property. Not such big overhead but avoidable. Also I'd move this responsibilities to separate methods:

```
void LoadChildrenAndUpdateUi(ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> childrenToFill)
{
    IsLoaded = true;

    var children = LoadChildren().ToArray();
    App.RunOnGuiThread(() =>
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
            childrenToFill.Add(child);
    });
}
```

And:

```
ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> EnsureChildrenAreLoaded(
    ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> childrenToFill, int depth)
{
    if (depth >= PRELOADING_DEPTH)
        return;

    if (!IsLoaded)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => LoadChildrenAndUpdateUi(myChildren));

    foreach (var child in myChildren)
        child.EnsureChildrenAreLoaded(child.myChildren, depth + 1);

    return myChildren;
}
```

Our getter will then be:

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> Children
    => EnsureChildrenAreLoaded(myChildren, 0);
```

Major difference is that we're going through the children to determine if they have to be loaded in the calling UI thread but we're queuing an action in the thread pool only when required. Note that we're using only one property to track the state (`IsLoaded`, which should be `private`). I set its value to `true` *before* effectively reading children to avoid multiple parallel requests, name is now somehow misleading and should be changed to something meaningful (`_isVisited` or something like that).

What next? If `PRELOADING_DEPTH` might ever be 0 or loading time may be really long then I'd add a *dummy* item to the child collection (to display the expand/collapse indicator), something like:

```
public TreeItemViewModel()
{
    Children.Add(new TreeItemViewModel { Name = "Loading..." });
}
```

Removed before you start adding new items:

```
children.Clear();
foreach (var child in children)
    childrenToFill.Add(child);
```

But, well, you already have a busy indicator then you don't need this at all!

---

**Edit**: if you're using `IsLoading` in your UI then, unfortunately, you can't drop it that easily. I think you have two options: replace `IsLoading` and `IsLoaded` with an `enum` like `enum LoadingStatus { NotLoaded, Loading, Loaded }` used in conjunction with a value converter to hide/show the busy indicator or use ordering (as you already doing) to avoid locks (because fortunately you have only one thread for writing):

```
var children = LoadChildren().ToArray();
App.RunOnGuiThread(() =>
{
    foreach (var child in children)
        childrenToFill.Add(child);

    IsLoaded = true;
    IsLoading = false;
});
```

Set `IsLoading` in the UI thread to avoid race conditions (both read and write will be then done in the same UI thread):

```
if (!IsLoaded && !IsLoading)
{
    IsLoading = true;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => LoadChildrenAndUpdateUi(myChildren));
}
```

---

Final notes.

If your depth is limited to direct children then you  may simplify your implementation (just invoke the lazy load method when you populate the list). You may also want to try to use a `LazyAsync<T>` implementation (I saw a nice one somewhere...can't find/remember where).

WPF supports **asynchronous binding** with a simple `IsAsync=true` in the binding expression. You may want to experiment with that, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx) for details

Comment: Thanks for your review. 1) Unfortunately, `IsLoading` is used to updated a busy indicator (as you correctly guessed ;)). Therefore it is not possible to drop the property.

Comment: 2) I like the way you restructured the reloading logic. It seems to be more reasonable. However, The condition should be `depth > PRELOADING_DEPTH`, isn't?

Comment: Unlucky! I'd use an `enum` here but it might be too much code for such simple task, especially because (fortunately!) with only one writing thread you do not need locks. I blindly inverted original condition (`<` to `>=`) but yes, it depends on the _meaning_ you give to `PRELOADING_DEPTH`

Comment: 3) Loading process is already indicated by a busy indicated (left to the item whose children are loaded), therefore the dummy item is not required. Otherwise it would be a great (and simple) solution to show the user that child items are currently loaded.

Comment: I am worry wheather "as soon as possible" is fast enough to AVOID race conditions :). What do you think about adding another instance variable of type int and use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to set a loading flag as atomic operation and avoid locking!?

Comment: @JanDotNet quite! As long as there is only one thread modifying the values (which you don't seem to be enforcing at the moment; an `Interlocked` flag would work well for such exclusion) and you don't really care about when the updates reach the UI thread then you don't need to lock anything. You might consider throwing in a memory barrier after `LoadChildren()` and before the `foreach` to ensure uptodateness (though I'd be amazed if `Invoke` didn't imply this already). If you do want to lock something, stick to `lock` (unless performance is critical, or it is impossible). enum is a good idea.

Comment: @JanDotNet I knew it wasn't clear (that's why italic) but I didn't find a better way to express the concept succinctly. I mean: it must be done before effectively starting the operation. Note that in this way  read/write are in the same (UI) thread then there isn't any _race_ with that flag, you do not need any synchronization primitive in this case (and code shouldn't be reordered in any way for currently supported .NET architectures, if in doubt...I think VisualMelon is right and a memory barrier is all you need)

Answer (score 2):

I am really unsure why you have a `public` access modifier for the `EnsureChildrenAreLoaded` method. I don't see any reason from the code why you would need it, and I think it should be at most `protected`, but preferably `private`.

For the `IsLoading` and `IsLoaded` members, I don't see why they should be members, and why you should be able to assign a value from outside your class. I think the should be private fields inside your class, cause nobody except the current `TreeItemViewModel` would care if they are loaded or not (and if they would, even then, I wouldn't allow it to be set from the outside)

To the outside, I would tend to give out only `IList<TreeItemViewModel>`, and keep the implementation of it hidden from the users. WPF will detected the `ICollectionChanged` interface, and will update on any changes (as long as you don't reassign)

I am also unsure if the `Name` of the TreeItemViewModel supports updates to the UI, if it does, it seems a part of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not yet implemented for it.

Comment: AFAIK an observable collection (instead of `IList` is required to support _automatic_ update when the collection is updated. Lock isn't necessary at all for a boolean property (per .NET memory model). `Name` isn't never updated after item is created then it doesn't need to be observable.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Actually, IList is enough, as long as you define the children as ObservableCollection<T>, wpf will detect the ICollectionChanged interface upon the binding. For the boolean property you are right. For the name, as I mentioned, I wasn't sure if you wanted it to updated ;)

Comment: Thx, agree that `EnsureChildrenAreLoaded` and setter of `IsLoaded` / `IsLoading`  should be private and properties should support change notification. Actually `IsLoading` does it in the current implementation ;).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: _Lock isn't necessary at all for a boolean property (per .NET memory model)_: Could you explain that? After reviewing it again, reading `IsLoading` and writing `IsLoading` are 2 distinct steps and therefore it is "critical section", isn't it?

Comment: @JanDotNet because we already dropped one of them, if you keep them both then of course writing both isn't atomic (but in that case I'd consider to use an `enum` instead). Even if we needed both, before adding a lock (any lock!), I'd consider if order might solve the issue (in this case we have only one writer and potentially only one reader).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Who is now the OP you, or JanDotNet. In the question, nothing seems to appear that they should be dropped.

Comment: @Icepickle because it's a _code review_, if something in code might be simplified then I think it should be (well...or at least we should _talk_ about it). In this case IMO there isn't the need to have them both.